# Проблема с pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Помогите
Пытаюсь сделать бота и пишет эту ошибку: https://pastebin.com/SGbeWWbQ
Код developersonly.py

```py
import discord
from discord.commands import command
class developerscog(discord.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        @bot.slash_command()
        @discord.option(name = "code", Type = str, required=True)
        async def eval(self, *, code):
            pass
```

Код main.py

```py
import discord
import logging
#import sqlite3
import pymongo
import cogs.modals as modals
import cogs.developersonly as developersonly
import dns.resolver


dns.resolver.default_resolver=dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers=['8.8.8.8']
clientdb = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = clientdb.test

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
intents = discord.Intents.default()
#con = sqlite3.connect('db/db.db')
#cur = con.cursor()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = discord.Bot()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.get_channel(1034164297317748779).send(content='Бот включился')


bot.add_cog(modals.modalscog(bot))
bot.add_cog(developersonly.developerscog(bot))
```